# generator vs break in list search

Tags: python, list, generator

I have a list of 100 000 elements and i have an element 4 at end of that list.

In this point, what is the difference between these approaches?

method 1:

```
def arr_f():
  for i in arr:
      if i==4:
          yield i
arr=[........100k entries]
gen_ob=arr_f()

for i in gen_ob:
    #do some op
```

Method 2:

```
def arr_f():
  for i in arr:
      if i==4:
          break
  else:
      return True
  return False
```

In Method 2 I am waiting for number 4 to come and break the loop if I hit it. In this case does the generator givs any advantage over method 2?

What I know on generator is it will yield a value on fly.
 In my case does my method 2 store more elements than method 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before delving into a comparison, I'll rewrite your functions so they are pure functions:

```
def f1(array, val):
    for i in array:
        if i == val:
            yield i
```

```
def f2(array, val):
    for i in array:
        if i == val:
            return False
    
    return True
```

I assumed you meant to return `False` if the value exists, and `True` otherwise. If not, please fix your indentation.

---

Unfortunately, comparing `f1` and `f2` does not make much sense because they seem to do different things. One simply yields multiple versions of `val`, while the other just checks whether `val` exists or not (and there are much simpler ways to do that).

> ### What is the difference between `f1(arr, 4)` and `f2(arr, 4)`, given `4` is the last element in `arr`?

The only difference is that `f1` returns a generator to iterate over, while `f2` returns a scalar `bool` value.

---

> ### What is the difference between `f1(arr, K)` and `f2(arr, K)` in a general scenario, where `K` is any value present anywhere in `arr`?

`f1` *does not stop* iterating after finding `K`. It will *always* continue to iterate over the entire list. So, the average, worst, and best case complexity is linear.

Meanwhile, `f2` finds the first occurrence of `K` and returns a value accordingly. Since `K` can be anywhere in the list, the run time of `f2` depends on your input.

Keep in mind that in any case, both have worst case linear complexities (`O(N)`).

Note that `f2` can be rewritten as:

```
def f2(array, val):
    return val not in array # you could convert to a set, but the conversion is linear, making the subsequent O(1) lookup pointless
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I have a value to search is appearing  only  once in the list, say  mid of the list, generator takes more time to execute? since it will look for the next call as well?

Comment: @syam Yes, since `yield` will cause execution to continue from where it left off. `return` causes a one-time exit and that's it.

Comment: @coldspeed one last question.... If my aim is to find all  occurrence of a particular number in a big list, using  generator or non generator method  does not make any difference  since i have to iterate through all members in the list. correct?

Comment: @syam Yes, you have to iterate over the whole thing either way. With a generator, you just delay that until you actually iterate over it (lazy evaluation).

Comment: awesome! Thanks!